# Is it possible to detect number of arguments in closure and execute accordingly?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, closures

I have 3x4x5 (or with more dimensions) array and I want for each position to pass coordinates to lambda function with its value.
However I can get _D,.. 3D, 2D or 1D closure where i need to emulate (for this example) 12x5 array and 60 positions array.

Is it possible in java to get number of arguments without much overhead and invoke this that way? Can I omit reflections and do it other way or is it unavoidable?

---EDIT---

Using varargs is not an option as functions created for manipulations were defined before or we don't want to make code too complicated.

So for example when we have 3D array which normally 3D closure would access by (x,y,z,val){} then for 2D closure I need to recognise this type of lambda and use it like (x+y*X.length,z,val).

Comment: Show some code, please.

Comment: you mean `(int... args)->{ int n=args.length; ...}`

Comment: Really. Add code examples.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really make sense. Every variable has a type. There is no "closure type". Rather, lambda expressions can be used in contexts that expect a functional interface type (an interface with exactly one method), and the lambda expression will evaluate to an object that implements that interface.

Since you have a known interface with exactly one method, that method has a known signature with a known number of arguments. Therefore, it doesn't make sense for you to not know the number of arguments.